# How do I execute a system command that requires user input and see the output in real time?

Tags: php, bash

When I run the following command and keep providing an empty passphrase:

```
mount -t ecryptfs /to/be/mounted /mount/location
```

I get:

```
Passphrase:
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
Passphrase:
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
Passphrase:
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
```

That's great!  But when I try doing the same from a PHP script with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
        system("mount -t ecryptfs /to/be/mounted /mount/location");
?>
```

I get:

```
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
Wrong input, non-empty value required!
Passphrase:
Passphrase:
Passphrase:
```

Not great!  How do I get PHP to display the output in the right order, at the right time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it relates to ,when PHP is running as a server module vs CGI, the system() call tries to automatically flush the web server's output buffer after each line of output.

Comment: It appears that the OP's script is running via CLI and not CGI, notice the shebang. However, you are correct regarding the output buffer, just not in the context of a web server.